# When Adding Dynamic YouTube Objects The Parameters Are Not Working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

When I add the YouTube players to my page, the 'rel' and 'end' parameters are not working. Everything else about the player works fun except these to parameters:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    $.each($(".ytiFrame"),function(index){
        ytPlayers[String($(this).attr("id"))] = new YT.Player(String($(this).attr("id")),{
            events: {
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            },
            videoId: $(this).data('video'),
            'rel':0,
            'end':3
        });
    })
}
```

As you can see, I'm adding the new YT.Player dynamically and the video embeds in the iFrame perfectly and plays just fine, and the event 'onStateChange' fires perfectly too.  But the 'rel' and 'end' parameters are not working at all.

I've also tried:

```
            rel:0,
            end:3
```

and:

```
            rel:'0',
            end:'3'
```

and:

```
            'rel':'0',
            'end':'3'
```

none made a difference and were ignored. In fact, when I look at the mark-up in debug, the iFrame doesn't even have these parameters listed.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question here:  [Adding additional parameters to the yt.player object from youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241151/adding-additional-parameters-to-the-yt-player-object-from-youtube)

Answer is to use this to add parameters:

```
playerVars: { 'rel': 0, 'end': 3 }
```